# How to arrange list items into columns on console

Tags: python

i want to arrange this list;

```
(11, 'CSS', 'Dickson Makale', '2017-02-03 14:48:23')
```

to samething like this:

```
11: CSS: Dickson Makale: 2017-02-03 14:48:23
```

i am printing the data from sqlite database

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like

```
": ".join(str(x) for x in (11, 'CSS', 'Dickson Makale', '2017-02-03 14:48:23'))
```

Comment: Thanks. that really worked